# Intellij JavaDoc not in sync or refreshing when I edit

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

What do I need to do to get Intellij to display the new edited version of my documentation when I view it (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).

For example if I create a new class the default template is added and the documentataion looks like this:

[image: Orig Doc Code]

And then will display like this:

[image: Initial Doc view]

If I then edit this to this:

[image: Edited Doc]

It still displays as the original documentaion (2nd image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had the documentation open previously, but pinned to the right hand side. Like below:

[image]

This meant that when I edited and tried to view it again it would display the old doc version which was pinned.

If I close that pinned window then the updated doc is displayed every time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have anything to do to have the "updated" javadoc displayed.

It is working as expecting for me, and it has been like that for years...

Comment: Well that is not what was happening for me. But I figured it out. I had the documentation open, but pinned to the right hand side. This meant that when I edited and tried to view it again it would display the old doc. I have to make sure I close the documentation window if I want to see the edited version